# Count words in a phrase - SQL

Tags: sql, hive, count, hue

If we have the phrase "My name is Mary". I would like to get the output of 4, as there are 4 words in the sentence.

I want this in SQL. I used the function length but it is counting by letter.

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming words are separated by a single space, you can use the count-and-replace method:

```
select length(str) - length(replace(str, ' ', '')) + 1
```

This counts the number of spaces and adds 1.

EDIT:

To handle multiple spaces in a row, you can tweak this as:

```
select length(regexp_replace(str, ' +', ' ')) - length(replace(str, ' ', '')) + 1
```

Comment: I think you're missing a `length` around the `replace`

Comment: I am getting this error.  I am using HQL.        "Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException Line 0:-1 Invalid function 'replace'" .  Any idea?

Comment: @Robbie . . . Your question is tagged "hive" and Hive definitely supports `replace()`.

Comment: @Robbie replace available as of Hive 1.3.0 and 2.1.0. Hive 1.2 is still in use a lot. Regexp_replace is a solution for hive <= 1.2

Comment: length(TEXT) - length(regexp_replace(TEXT, ' ', '')) + 1
This worked. Can you guys help to try to understand what this i doing please?

Comment: @Robbie . . . This takes the length of the string.  It then removes the spaces and recalculates the length.  The difference between these two is the number of spaces.  One more than that number is the number of words.

Comment: Nice, I have tested this and does not work well with cases like, double space, or Hi.there (It would take it as one). Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out:

```
select size(split(str, " ")) from your_table;
```

Or:

```
select length(regexp_replace(str, '[^ \t\r\n\v\f]', '')) + 1 from your_table;
```

Comment: @Robbie what is the problem?

Comment: Can you provide an example of such behavior?